# What should be done about users only asking about how to spam?

Tags: discussion, users

I just stumbled over [this question (Autoclick a link using Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138105/autoclick-a-link-using-javascript) and became a bit suspicious about the intent (aka it's a blatant "help me spam/advertise" question).

Are there any sort of measures I (a low rep user) can take except downvote the question and raise a moderator flag?

And perhaps more importantly, should anything be done to stop this user or are they in their right to ask these questions (not taking the question quality into account)?

Comment: Sort of related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262656/should-questions-about-programming-viruses-and-malware-be-allowed

Comment: I think this is only worth considering if we had an example question that was otherwise of good quality. This question is terrible, so we should treat it like a terrible question.

Comment: @OGHaza Duly noted and edited in.

Comment: Their email addresses should be posted so we can return the favour.

Comment: I think one enters dangerous territory when presuming to judge peoples motives for asking a question. What "we" (meaning you) should do about a question you don't like is not answer it.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to follow Jimmy Buffett's advice: breathe in, breathe out, move on. Have a little trust in the other users & mods, and figure that they'll "get it" and slam-dunk the question in short order - which in this case is exactly what happened.

Comment: I regularly downvote and vote to close as off-topic questions that are obviously about writing malware. The type of question OP is referring to sounds less clear-cut, in which case I might just ignore it or post  comment.

Answer (score 68):

I say answer the question.  What the user does with the knowledge of how to spam is simply not your concern or mine.

Maybe they are experimenting with user interface designs, and will shortly conclude it is a bad idea.  Maybe they have a private, local-only web console for their own use that fires on mouse-over.  There's no way for us to know or control how this knowledge will be used.

Imagine the same philosophy being applied on the Information Security exchange.  [At](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57541/how-fast-can-a-md5-collision-be-found) [least](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10702/is-a-wireless-receiver-a-security-weak-point) [some](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61094/what-are-the-weaknesses-of-wpa-with-tkip) [of](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64601/ip4v-rainbow-table) [these](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32663/can-files-deleted-from-a-true-crypt-volume-be-recovered) [questions](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2403/some-good-resources-on-viruses-worms) would have to be closed, and many more I think.  The cryptography world has learned, perhaps counter-intuitively, that openly and publicly discussing "dangerous" knowledge yields better results than keeping everything secret.

The idea of "not educating the immoral" is very old in the world and very tempting, but I believe it is usually not correct, unless a very direct cause and effect path leading to "bad things" can be drawn.  Because ultimately, such a decision is based on the judgement of another person.

Of course, it's altogether different if somebody asks "how can I hack into Company X's network?" or other such.  But such a question would not be appropriate on the site anyway, due to being overly specific.

Comment: After the user has done enough spamming he may be able to afford his college degree.

Comment: So we are simply put; teaching kids how to make firecrackers, not psychopaths how to make pipe bombs?

Comment: Also consider the impact on other people reading the QA. They might be trying to fight such things, and learning how it works can make them more efficient than having them wonder how the spammers do it

Comment: Doesn't look like SO agreed.  The question has been deleted. @.@

Comment: @LaymanCoder According to other comments, it was judged as a poor question on other grounds.  Which to me is totally unsurprising.  In my opinion, a good quality question on subjects like spam is much more likely to fall in the domain of legitimate research.

Answer (score 17):

This is a social issue. You do not condone that he is earning money by scamming (neither do I). You do not want him to negatively affect society.

Stack Overflow is not in the business of policing social interaction, though. Be careful when you judge what people should or should not do outside of Stack Overflow. This is not for us to judge because it is a very subjective decision about right and wrong.

I recommend that you just don't answer and leave it at that. If you feel comfortable answering the question, by all means, answer it.

Comment: "scam" != "spam"

Answer (score 7):

I would say:

If you **don't like the question, ignore it.** If this guy is really *advertising*, he/she will find other ways to the solution of autoclicking. IE: from other coding communities, official documentation and books. We don't want to judge people in the public here, as I had said, leave it where it is if you don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

While SO does not police morally questionable questions or questions that only have illegal applications, if you are a member of a professional body you may have submitted to a code of conduct that is incompatible with assisting people in these pursuits.

Here, for example, is the [British Computer Society's Code of Conduct](http://www.bcs.org/category/6030) which contains such instructions as:

> You shall have due regard for the legitimate rights of Third Parties

The [Association of Information Professionals Code of Ethics](http://c.ymcdn.com/sites/www.aitp.org/resource/resmgr/forms/code_of_ethics.pdf) states:

> To the best to my ability, insure that the products of my work are used in a socially 
>   responsible way.

Even if you are not a member of a professional body, you could still elect to subscribe to a sensible moral code.