# Eradicate [virus]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

Looking through the [virus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virus) tag, most of the questions seem to be off-topic. Half of the questions on the first page are already closed. Questions about programming viruses would be on-topic, but from [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262656/should-questions-about-programming-viruses-and-malware-be-allowed), that doesn't seem to be encouraged. So this seems to match point 2 of [When to burninate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191).

**Edit:** This seems to also fit with #3 - in a programming context, the tag by itself tells nothing about the question.  It's simply the method of distribution for the final product. None of the top questions would be helpful resources for a beginning [virus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virus) programmer, unlike most on-topic tags.

As an example, here's the top three questions tagged with only [virus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virus):

[Books on Computer Viruses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157961/books-on-computer-viruses)

[Execute a file in sandboxed environment and track it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259319/execute-a-file-in-sandboxed-environment-and-track-it)

[Best way to obtain virus/malware samples and examine them safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178621/best-way-to-obtain-virus-malware-samples-and-examine-them-safely)

Two of them are closed already, and the third isn't on topic either.

Comment: I work for an MSP, and one of my co-workers is always burninating a virus! But seriously; I think that tag can be useful here.

Comment: @AndrewBarber It could be, if used properly. But it appears to be attracting mostly off-topic questions.

Comment: That much, I do not doubt whatsoever. Without even looking.

Comment: Maybe the question could be rephrased asking for a Clean up.

Comment: @bummi that would be a fools task, it would be like fighting against the tide. Also, the topic of "virus" is [not relevant in a programming context](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/213575). Who cares if you are writing a virus or if your system has virus?

Comment: @Braiam - quite a lot of people.

Comment: Of the questions tagged "virus" that are still open, I'd say that something like 90% of them are obviously off-topic. Burn it.

Comment: @duskwuff that percentage strangely coincide with the saying that "90% of everything is crap" ;)

Comment: We also certainly cannot have [users creating viruses...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23942144/i-accidentally-created-a-virus-just-how-is-this-a-virus)

Comment: I think discussion of viruses is better suited to security.SE anyways. I say burninate it.

Comment: It would be ridiculous to get rid of a perfectly good tag which can certainly be used in an on-topic context just because some of the questions it was tagged with are bad.  By your logic, PHP should have been nuked from orbit years ago.

Comment: @Brad PHP certainly has a high percentage of terrible questions, but I'm not using that as the sole criteria. In a non-programming context, it's obviously off topic. Considering the linked discussion in my question, the use of `virus` in a programming context is dubious. And what does `virus` really say about the question? It doesn't tell the language, it doesn't really give any information other than the intended method of distribution. I can't point to any of the top questions as a good resource for beginning `virus` programmers, unlike PHP and many on-topic tags.

Comment: -1 because you can't dis*infect* a virus. Well, I suppose you can... but can we please just burninate? I don't want to get that close to it.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah, rolled back. Not sure why it didn't notify me of the edit.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361000/8456454 a similar [tag:antivirus] burnination request.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with burnination of this tag. Since this question was posted on Jan 1, there have been 36 questions posted with this tag.

As far as I could tell, the only ones that were on-topic and anywhere near relevant were these ones:

[C# app appears false positive in AVG antivirus?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28775519/656243)

[Codedom Dynamic code generation detected as a virus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29479824/656243)

..and their use-case is weak.

As of today, we're starting a close-vote campaign in the [SO Close-Voters Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) to close out all applicable questions in preparation for burnination of this tag. Please do not remove the tag from any questions at this time.

As of 10/08/2015, there are [**234 open questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bvirus%5D+closed%3Ano) with this tag.

Comment: A whopping 316 questions ever had that tag: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/373167/questions-which-ever-had-a-tag?tag=virus (excluding this week)

Answer (score -9):

While there may not be many good questions now, it is definitely a valid topic with the potential for good questions. I recall at my university, in the computer science library there was a self dedicated to virus and writing detecting them etc. I think it;s appropriate to keep the tag.

Comment: Right now there are _a lot of broken windows_ in the [tag:virus] tag. So even _if it did_ contribute something to the question (I have no idea _what_ that would be) the tag would need a serious clean up.

Comment: Well questions about writing virus or how they work would be fair game so it seems strange to delete it. I could see deleting all the current questions, but it seems like a tag we'll eventually have good questions for.

Comment: @ArtB There is the remote possibility of good questions, that's why I only suggested burnination instead of black-listing. I see it as remote because there are a lot of people who just want help getting rid of a virus, offtopic or not, and I don't expect those to leave any time soon.