# How to flag a question about abusing a system?

Tags: discussion, flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497881/how-can-google-know-im-faking-my-user-agent)

is based on an abusive idea*.

How to flag questions that are based on misusing? The question mentioned may be "too broad", but that's not the point. It is about "misusing" or "abusing", yet not "hacking". It's not spam. It is also neither offensive, which seems to be in the context of "hatred" (I'm not native).

Or: not to flag at all, downvote and set a comment that asks for clarification about the intention, to help solving the real problem?

---

<sub>* "abusive" has its shades. But if I were the sysadmin of a system someone wants to generate fake accounts for on a daily basis, I wouldn't like it.</sub>

#### Question below for < 10K users

[image]

Comment: +1, I'm having a similar problem with [a post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149372/c-sharp-possible-to-search-google-by-image-and-downloading-the-first-one) that started as a technical question but the OP turned it into one about circumventing API quota limits.

Comment: @MártonMolnár 'what do you mean legal? ' - posters like this should be banned.   They are effectively trying to draw SO contributors into a conspiracy to defraud, (or some other offence).  It's immoral, inconsiderate and irreverent to ask such questions on here.  I down or close vote all such questions I see.   The lawyers, prosecutors and TLAs can go knock on someone else's door, I want none of it.

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262656/should-questions-about-programming-viruses-and-malware-be-allowed

Comment: @MártonMolnár I don't see anything strictly wrong with the question you've linked nor good answer you've provided. "I don't want to pay" clause is not much different from `"select ... where n="+passwordTextbox.Text` code seen all the time - the fact that OP want to do things in any particular broken way does not mean answer should help doing so - you provide canonical answer to actual question and often it is "no, you can't/shouldn't do {that}. You can do {this} instead".

Comment: I'd much rather questions were judged on their merits and not get into the slippery slope of guessing and judging the morality of a motivation, or legality of some ToS/contract between third parties. Morally dubious questions are almost always terrible and forcing the good ones to lie/spin wins us nothing.

Comment: I don't think there is any prohibition on hacking questions as such. Surely these questions are a benefit, since it teaches readers how to combat security threats? Banning them here is of no use at all, since such material is very easily available all over the internet.

Comment: It was a very interesting question, and the answers to it could have been used to improve existing applications to also be able to block said fake user agents on our own servers. too bad it was too broad.

Comment: How did it get an undelete vote?

Comment: tag them as opinion based

Comment: Can you post a screenshot for future reference?

Comment: @jakekimds - Done

Comment: Things we might judge to be "immoral" on the surface, like hacking/abuse of services, can sometimes be used for activism and significantly improve the world. Usually not, but sometimes...

Comment: @anshabhi Absolutely do *not* randomly flag them as opinion based. Find a flag that fits or leave it alone. "Opinion based" doesn't come close to appropriate for this situation.

Comment: I think, if worded better with a sense of learning a concept in mind, the question would be good for the InfoSec site, since OP is trying to bypass a security measure and (seems that he) wants to know why he is being asked these security questions in different settings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your all contributions, answers and edits. It seems the question is of a certain relevance. Last days I've had too much other things on the desk, but I'd like to come back soon to rewording, or doing other suggested means to improve the question to the level of a good contribution. I'm glad this discussion is possible.

Answer (score 45):

Technically, questions about hacking or circumventing blocks aren't disallowed on SO.
***Provided*** that they are *proper* questions that focus on technical issues.

The question you linked to was way too broad, there were way too many possible answers.
Questions like that will (and should) get **downvoted and closevoted.**

I'm sure a portion of the downvotes on there was solely based on the questionable activities described. *Technically*, that's not necessarily a good downvote reason, but a user has the right to vote as he sees fit. Often enough, there are other reasons to downvote a question like that. For example, personally, I would have downvoted that question based on the fact that it's way too broad.

However, if the user would have left out the whole *"creating multiple Gmail accounts"* backstory, and if he would've put some more effort into the question itself*, the question could have been good enough.

<sub>**: He could have given some examples (even guesses) at what might be happening.*</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. - "Being disallowed" and "being not appreciated" are two things. Is it not in the interest of StackOverflow not to appreciate a question like (e.g.) "Does somebody know how to exploit IE 10 in order to get admin permissions on the client machine?" Does this end up in "the knife can be used several ways?", so everything is appreciated?

Comment: Oh, questions like these definitely aren't appreciated. Often enough, there are other reasons to close them, though. _"Does somebody know how to exploit <x>"_, for example, is way too broad. _"How do I force entry in <system x>"_ is too broad. _"I need a tool to crack <X>"_ is a library / tool request (Which has it's very own closure reason).

Comment: ^^ ^^ ^^ Ok. But _if_ the question was of good quality and _if_ it wasn't appreciated, there would be no suitable flag? ...People would probably choose _some_ flag...

Comment: If the question is of good quality, there is no reason to flag it.
I honestly can't think of a good quality question about a subject like this. Any way, when in doubt, don't flag it. You can always downvote the question.

Comment: And leave a comment why you downvoted the question, so that OP could edit the question and add the missing stuff and come up with what he tried so far.

Comment: Leaving comments with your votes isn't required, though. However, it often _is_ appreciated.

Comment: @Cerbrus I try to help new users with a comment to help them understand how the community works and how is it different from other forums. Else, the poster keeps wondering why so many downvotes and not a single comment to explain the reason.

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't comment with a vote, I'm just saying it isn't mandatory, but appreciated.

Comment: @Cerbrus "Leaving comments ... often is appreciated" - unfortunately as I see it such comments way more often ignored/misinterpreted rather than appreciated. Strictly personal choice to add comment, also I doubt OP of that "have problem when violating user agreement" question need any comments why it is downvoted :)

Comment: More times than not, when i downvote and leave a comment, the op still complains about the downvote not having a comment.

Answer (score 12):

> How to flag questions that are based on misusing?

I don't see a reason it is Stack Overflow's jurisdiction to remove questions related to hacking a system or related to circumventing the restrictions ona system. You might never know OP's intention unless OP states his intentions with the provided solution to his question.

I agree, that question is too broad, and it ended up well to be closed as "Too Broad". There is nothing to flag in that question, you have two options:

- Downvote and leave a comment why you downvoted
- Close (if it fits one of the categories to close it)

By the way, since the user has openly said that he creates multiple "Gmail" accounts, perhaps he has made the community aware. If the user tries to make any of his attempt here, you know his fate.

> "abusive" has its shades. But if I were the sysadmin of a system someone wants to generate fake accounts for on a daily basis, I wouldn't like it.

I completely agree with your opinion. However, that is a personal opinion and Stack Overflow wouldn't disallow such questions.

There are so many questions related to database where OP wants to know how to login/access a database without password authentication. And they have had been answered. We don't know OP's intention behind it, whether he wants to do that on his production system or just curious to know. Whatever the reason be, it doesn't stop the user to post his question or someone to answer the question.

> Or: not to flag at all, downvote and set a comment that asks for clarification about the intention, to help solving the real problem?

This question was too broad, so I would vote to close it as "Too Broad". And that's what happened.

If you don't know whether or not to close the question, and if you have a reason to downvote it, then downvote it and possibly leave a comment, don't flag it.

To conclude, I don't see a reason to flag the question as "abusing any system". It is closed, which is correct.

Comment: *"I don't see a reason it is Stack Overflow's jurisdiction"* - that is the wrong word.  (Or if you really do mean "jurisdiction", then you are wrong.)  StackExchange is a private company, and it has a right to say what is or is not acceptable, and to authorize others (e.g. moderators and high-rep users) to participate in the "judgement".

Comment: @StephenC I appreciate your comment. First of all, judgement and jurisdiction are two different words, and words have their meaning. Secondly, you have quoted a part of statement which has changed it's complete meaning. You should quote my complete statement `I don't see a reason it is Stack Overflow's jurisdiction to remove questions related to hacking a system or related to circumventing the restrictions on a system.`. Now please explain where you think otherwise?

Comment: @StephenC Oh, by the way, to reiterate in your words, *"stack overflow is a private company and it has the right to say what is acceptable or not. And the posted question shouldn't be flagged as abusive as there is no evidence to support it"*.

Comment: The legal system in the US is extremely litigious. If someone was to get a piece of code here that they used to try and do something illegal/bypass some sort of paywall and get caught it would be  a pretty easy leap to involve SO. Especially if it was at least moderately clear in the users question that they intended to bypass some system. I would say avoiding the possibility of SO being approached by an especially ambitious lawyer seeking damages is worth a flag for moderation.

Answer (score 1):

The original question was deleted so I don't know what it was about, but I will weigh in about the `abusing` aspect of the question.

I strongly feel that this on it's own it isn't a reason for flagging/deleting a question (or an answer). My argument is that knowing how to abuse a system is a tool, and as with any tool it can be used to do good or bad or even illegal things. It could be for instance that the OP wants or has the job to stress-test, find vulnerabilities or find the limits of a system.

Unless it is clear that the **intent** is to do harm, these questions shouldn't be flagged.

If however there is genuine concern about the intent of doing harm or taking illegal actions the post should be flagged for a moderator with a comment on the suspicion and reason of it.

Comment: Questions with the intent to cause harm don't necessarily need to be flagged. Just downvoting and closevoting them should be plenty.