# What to do with questions asking to break companies'/schools' security rules?

Tags: discussion, ethics, security

I wonder how this type of question should be treated, as it seems to encourage piracy or security outage?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582778/is-there-a-file-that-runs-like-a-batch-file-but-does-not-involve-cmd-or-run

I don't think it is a duplicate of [Should questions about programming viruses and malware be allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262656) as this user has a really low reputation and seems more interested in "hacking" his school security rule rather than to learn something about programming...

Comment: If only the OP had just asked for a command-line alternative, instead of going on about how he wants to play minecraft at school. Still, technically, there are no rules against this, on SO.

Comment: For this particular question, I close as too broad, since it's not possible to know the extent of the block.

Comment: asker can ask anything, but moderator can remove this type of question and user can flag that

Comment: @BhavinSolanki on the other hand this could be interpreted as censorship not sure if flagging is appropriate here.

Comment: @BhavinSolanki: An asker can't ask _anything_. Questions should follow SO's rules and guidelines.

Comment: @rene please see my edit, I don't think this user wants to learn something except breaking a specific security rule ....

Comment: The problem with the linked question, and _virus_ questions is the same.

Comment: I guess there is not absolute answer to this. In this case I keep thinking the OP is a script kiddie, I've opted to close his question as too broad.