# Programming questions with bad/malicious/fraudulent intention of OP

Tags: discussion, review-queues, moderation

While reviewing, I recently came to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930292/need-javascript-without-cookies-saved) which seems to be OK until you look closely. [(archived link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170322175035/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42930292/need-javascript-without-cookies-saved) (March 22, 2017 5:50:35 PM UTC)

There, the OP has NO knowledge of JavaScript (he/she couldn't even understand the hint provided by some other users in the comment section) and trying to use other users to write code for him/her which will be used to spam other unsuspecting users visiting his/her website.

In the question, he/she referred to a website for his/her problem. http://25-gb-data.in/ In the first step, they collect user personal information, then they ask to share this message to nine WhatsApp contacts (spamming). They count for user click (OP asked help regarding this part) and then redirect to another page where they are forced to download & install a software. After that, there is no other step. They claim that order has been placed, but there is not even any code on the page to process the information on server-side.

```
if(c < 4)
{
window.alert("You have not installed All Apps in your mobile.\n Please complete Install it.");
}
else
{
window.alert("Thank you for purchased. \n\nWe have received your application. \n\nYour order number is IAT5148R3. \n\nYour order will be placed soon. \n\nRemember : Don't Uninstall these apps till received item.")
}
```

This is a classic example of tricking other users who have little Internet knowledge.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**While the question is related to programming (and doesn't fit into any pre-defined closing request), the intention of the OP is clearly bad.**

I think StackOverflow should have some social responsibility (I am sure about the proper term), not to help such script kiddies who are just here to get ready-made codes.

The bad intention of the OP is beyond doubt and I raised a "moderator intervention" flag, but my request was denied with the message:

> declined - please use the standard close reasons to close questions, rather than the 'requires moderator attention' flags

I am new to reviewing and IMHO, this question should be closed. If you still think this question is OK, can you please tell me proper reasons so that I can learn more about moderation?

Comment: downvoting would be a valid moderation action to take. Negatively scored not-positivily answered questions get automagically deleted.

Comment: From the screenshot, I think you did all the tasks?? :-).  I came across a similar question which pointing to the same link. I just raised a spam flag and it is removed.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262656/should-questions-about-programming-viruses-and-malware-be-allowed

Comment: @KevinB, thank you. I just wanted to know what should I do in this case.

Comment: @Kara, thank you for pointing out. I will take a look

Comment: @SagarV yes. I have a lot of friends/relatives who don't clearly understand how the internet works and easily become victims of such fraudulent/bad users. So I take these actions little personally. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link isn't actually important to what the question is asking.  You could edit the link out of the question rather easily without changing what it's asking.

As for closure, the question seems very unclear to me; I'd vote to close as such.  It's also just a requirements dump asking to build a whole feature for them, because they can't be bothered to, so closing as Too Broad would be fine for that reason.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep these things in mind to review questions in future :)