# Should we remove questions that ask with help violating a software license?

Tags: discussion, scope

I, along with several other users, voted to close [Visual studio 2017 unable to backspace, tab, or produce much functionality at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982851) ([screenshot in case the question gets deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMOvB.png)) because it asked for assistance with violating a software license. The user there mentioned they thought this was allowed because they had seen another question asking the same thing, and indeed were trying to use the advice from [Visual studio 2015 CTP Trial expired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512908). That question was fairly popular, gathering multiple upvotes and 20K views over its lifetime. I know that Stack Exchange is particularly hesitant to remove popular questions because of the hit to page views, even when the questions would otherwise be off topic. So I flagged the question with the text:

> This is a highly popular question, but it's asking for (and receiving) help with violating a software license. Now other questions such as 47982851 are being asked in reference to it, so it's setting a bad example.

The flag was declined with the response:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

I would think that a popular question on Stack Overflow explaining how to violate a software license and pirate the software would be something a moderator should take a look at. Voting to close an extremely old/popular question isn't likely to remove the content. And leaving that content around is just likely to be used as justification for others to do it in the future.

Was I right to flag this for a moderator? And should we be removing these sorts of questions?

Comment: As a 20k user, you have the ability to vote to delete the questions you mentioned. I see no delete votes on either. If you feel this was worthy of a moderator flag, why haven't you cast delete votes of your own?

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262749/7296893). We're not cops ;)

Comment: @BradLarson I can't delete in its current state. I have now voted to close, using a custom reason. I didn't think that would be necessary since I didn't think the flag would be declined. And as I pointed out in my question, I would think that a moderator would want to be quick to clean up an upvoted and popular question that asks for help with violating software licenses. And still, my overall question remains: should we be voting to close these?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think this falls under "blatantly an irresponsible script kiddie looking for someone to help them break a specific system, and the question is too specific to be of use to future readers" from the top answer on that question. They're not an irresponsible script kiddie, but they are looking for help to break a specific system, and it's a specific question about an old piece of software that isn't likely to help anyone with legitimate needs.

Comment: As a moderator, I'm not qualified to judge license terms, copyrights (particularly across the various nations represented here), codes of conduct, and other third-party rules. All I can do is judge whether a question or answer is a good fit technically for this website. As is pointed out in the link above, sometimes on topic questions that may violate some license are of utility to the broader community here. Since the outrage of a few years ago, moderators generally leave it to the community to vote to close / delete popular questions.

Comment: @mason isn't likely to help anyone with _legitimate_ needs, no (legitimate being US/EU law, not complying with a license is legal in quite a few countries. Distribution is something else). But apparently able to help quite a few people (seeing the number of views and upvotes).

Comment: @BradLarson Fine, being voted a moderator doesn't automatically make you an expert on software licenses. But is it not clear that specifically asking for help to bypass a screen that locks trial software is a violation of a software license? It doesn't take an expert to figure that out. And even though this is old software and there are great free alternatives, leaving such a question in place can and will and has been used as justification for others to ask similar questions. I noticed you haven't voted to close it either, despite being made aware of it. So is it SO policy to allow these?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Legal or not legal, we're all software developers here. We have to make a living. If we actively assist users with pirating software, isn't that counter productive and immoral and self defeating?

Comment: Questions about morality are quite loaded. I tend to like viewing such questions to learn what _not_ to do (such as leaving the software fully functional and just displaying a modal dialog in your example question). Personally, I dislike hiding knowledge. I would not answer such a question, though, or develop/refer to software to crack something.  If you can do it without any external tools, it's bad security, and as soon as someone needs/asks for tools, you can close -> request for off-site resource. But the dupe makes sense since it's against the TOS for SO to help.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I'm not arguing against the dupe. I'm asking: are these sorts of questions allowed on Stack Overflow? And if not, why hasn't anyone besides me voted to close it despite being brought to several people's attention? And if it is allowed, then why aren't people voting to re-open the question I helped close? We're being hypocritical by allowing one to stay open and not the other.

Comment: Well, you've convinced me since it's against the TOS, so we should close it. It has my vote. You can bring it up in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if you want it closed quickly

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I considered that, but now I'm genuinely curious. If Brad, an experienced moderator, hasn't voted to close it despite having seen it, maybe the official policy is to keep it around?

Comment: @mason Moderators don't vote on every post they read.  They're *exception handlers*.  They're there to resolve problems that the community cannot resolve.  For example, if there's a dispute over whether a question should be open or closed that is becoming unconstructive, then they'd step in, but a mod isn't obligated to close every question they ever read that merits closure.  They often try to let the community handle things that they are able to handle without issue; community run site and all.  Don't take a mods inaction as a sign that the question doesn't merit closure.

Comment: Now the linked derived question is gone, I suggest we do the same with its parent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26512908/visual-studio-2015-ctp-trial-expired/34243422#34243422

Comment: Such a question *could* be helpful when somebody points out that there is a freeware edition available of the product.  But it seems to be difficult to get an answer like that.  Too boring an answer, in the land of the blind the animated gif is king.  We can't win them all.