# Pattern of questions indicates a user is writing malware

Tags: discussion, specific-question, ethics, specific-user

I just came across [a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11187835/yesii-0691) who, by their pattern of questions, is apparently writing a virus and using Stack Overflow for help with it. We've [already discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262656/7509065) the issue of when a single question is clearly for malware, but this case is different. None of the user's questions are by themself purely for writing malware, but the pattern of them is unambiguously so:

- [Exploit development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55503298/7509065)
- [Self-modifying code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55780254/7509065) (lots of questions, but just linking to one here)
- [Anti-reverse engineering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55802488/7509065) - In particular, this question indicates that it's not just for learning how malware works

Does the fact that these are separate (and on their own, innocuous) change anything from the previous discussion? Should we continue answering this user's questions?

Comment: Well, how do you propose we stop them? Site policy has generally been that it's better to have the information out in the open. Of course, the vast majority of these questions are of abysmally low quality, so they can be stopped in another way...

Comment: @Makoto I'm aware of that question (I even linked to it!) - are you sure this is a dupe?

Comment: @joseph-sible: the duplicate states that it is even ok to ask single questions about maleware development as long as they are of good quality and don't hide the fact. I'm assuming that if something is ok for a single question, then it is also ok for a series of questions.

Comment: I just down/close vote them without any further consideration.  If other users wish to help, and potentially get swept up in any legal or other actions that may result, it's their risk.

Comment: @JosephSible I find that linking to specific questions you've looked at on meta contributes to it being linked as a dupe even if you explain why its not in your original question lol